# How to make a chart that sorts occurrences in a chart based on year

Tags: google-sheets, charts, bar-chart, spreadsheet

How can I make a chart in google sheets that has the years(2018,2019,2020,2021,2022) on the x axis and the count(how many occurrences in that year on a sheet) on the y axis, similar to this? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n2y6.jpg)

I tried using a bar graph, but I don't know how to alter the x axis in this way.

Comment: Share a test sheet showcasing your input data + what you've tried with the graph so that we can pick it up from there. You may also use this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) for ease of sharing just in case...

Comment: within the Chart>Series setting you have the option to select *right-vertical-axis* for `distance` & *Left-axis* for `flight count`

Comment: @rockinfreakshow here is the link to the test sheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YTkK7XW8DrwsVzu6ODNt2ONctFtrDMrbe9l-TwTZslI/edit) Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've added a formula in Column_K + a test graph for you to check out

Answer (score 0):

*Extracted just the `year` into a separate column & created the bar graph by **aggregating the COUNT** of years available in the range :*

```js
=arrayformula(if(len(G2:G),year(G2:G),))
```

[image]